# How to override default font-size of Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, font-size

I have used Bootstrap for a dropdown Navbar and after that, I have designed a responsive two column gird. My main aim is that, the right column must have the image and the left column must have a responsive font size.

My HTML code for the same is:

```
  <div class="body">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="text-responsive">
        <h4>Occupation</h3>
        <h1>N a m e</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">Image will come here</div>
  </div>
```

My CSS code is:

```
.body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.text-responsive {
  font-size: calc(100% + 1vw + 1vh) !important;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #1B263B;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.body {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px;
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: 5fr 2fr;
  }
}
```

The grid is responsive, but I want my font-size to also change along with the device I'm using. Any help would be appreciated! I know that Bootstrap has default font-sizes but is there no way to override those values? I tried adding "!important", but it didn't work. Also I am not using Bootstrap for my responsive grid so why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector does not target the elements on which bootstrap sets the font size (`h1` and `h4` elements).
The declaration below will make the font size of all `h4`s inside `.text-responsive` responsive.

```
.text-responsive h4 {
  font-size: calc(100% + 1vw + 1vh);  
}
```

Comment: "Your selector does not have enough specificity" — It uses `!important`. Specificity isn't the problem. The problem is that it doesn't target the elements on which the font size is set in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin, I stand corrected. I've edited my answer.